# ADCIRC - Cannot find -lhdf5_fortran: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, make, fortran

Trying to compile ADCIRC, a Fortran program with NetCDF support, and I hit the following error.

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_fortran: No such file or directory`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I am a little confused as to which file it is looking for as it cannot find any file named lhdf5_fortran.

I have the libhdf5-dev and libhdf5-fortran-102 libraries installed.
I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: The file's actual name would be `libhdf5_fortran.so`. Are you trying to build with HDF5 serial or MPI? If the latter, which implementation (mpich or openmpi)?

Comment: I'm using HDF5 serial. So changing the flag to libhdf5_fortran.so should work?

Comment: No, that won't work, `ld` *infers* the name from the option. If you've installed the libhdf5-dev package you should find `libhdf5_fortran.so` somewhere (check with `dpkg -L libhdf5-dev | grep fortran` for example). The issue *may* be that Ubuntu places it in a `serial/` subdirectory - there may be a configuration flag / variable you need to set to tell it that.

Comment: It's the latter! Changing the flag to lhdf5_serial_fortran did the trick. On Ubuntu the file is named libhdf5_serial_fortran.so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @steeldriver, Ubuntu places libhdf5_fortran under serial, and changing the flag to `libhdf5_serial_fortran` in the cmplrflags file works.

Comment: Not that you'll get reputation, but you should always mark an answer as an answer, even if it's your own.